# select first sql

Tags: sql, arrays

I have the following selection:

```
$selectSql2 = "SELECT FIRST(selector_buttongroup_classes) AS data_car_type 
               FROM cars WHERE selector_isactive = 1 AND publish = 1;";
```

I know selector_buttongroup_classes has data because I use it in another array.  But it is returning a value of null for each data_car_type in the array when I return it to my function.

So I am assuming the issue has to do with using FIRST??

Comment: Is this an MS Access database? Don't know any other db that uses that syntax (talking about the FIRST-command)..

Comment: To support @Mackan, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about sql, you have mistaken it with First() function in MS Access. There are no First() function in SQL. I think you want to get the first record of specified column. 
So the workaround in sql is use TOP as follows

```
$selectSql2 = "SELECT TOP 1 selector_buttongroup_classes AS data_car_type FROM cars WHERE selector_isactive = 1 AND publish = 1;";
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Technically, MS Access uses an SQL dialect with Jet/ACE engine and one available aggregate is First() and Last(). All databases have particular functions and methods while running SQL (i.e., MySQL does not support OUTER JOIN, or TOP like in your answer; PostgreSQL allows procedural functions). Hardly any db runs primarily true ANSI SQL.

Comment: Still get a null value using the SELECT TOP 1 option

Answer (score 0):

I am using MySQL,  For each row of about 100 rows, I need the first item in a list of items inside a column in a table.  So if the column in the first row contained         `honda convertible four-wheel drive`

I would need to pick off Honda.  And if the next row and same column contained

`mazda hardtop two-wheel drive`

I would need to pick off mazda.

I was trying to do it in the ajax call which is where my select call above came in.  But perhaps a better solution would be to do it in the function that gets the data after the return.  Since one of the items I am returning is all of the data in that particular column (in addition to other columns in the array).  The column is selector_buttongroup_classes.  Here is my function:

```
displayCars();

function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       var resultArray = data.isotopecubes;
       var resultArray2 = data.isotopecubes2;
       var selectorDiv = $('#boat_isotope_gallery');
       var divHtml = '';

          var i = 0;

          for (i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {

              divHtml +=  "<div class='element-item " + resultArray[i].selector_buttongroup_classes + "' data-range-test='100-400' " + resultArray[i].selector_sliderdata_attributes + " ><h3 class='name'>" + resultArray[i].product_name + "</h3><p class='weight'><img src='" + resultArray[i].photo + "' width='80' border='0' alt=''></p></div>"; 
          }

        selectorDiv.html(divHtml);
    },
    error : function(err) {
        console.log('ajax failure');
    }
});
```

}
}); // end of document ready